# How to change shortcut for switching chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, mac

I currently have my shortcut for changing tabs in chrome as  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>←</kbd>  which is the default. This would either require both hands, or require one hand to be in a very awkward position, so I want to change the shortcut to a more convenient one.

I've looked through system preference -> keyboard -> shortcuts, and can't find the default shortcut for me to change.

Where / how can I change the shortcut for changing tabs in chrome?

I am on a Mac, and this is a screenshot of my system preferences where I've looked to try to change the shortcut.
[image: Systems Preferences]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change it in App Shortcuts, at the bottom of that window.

However, before you do, check the appropriate menu item for next/prev tab - Chrome usually defaults to  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   &  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>

[image]

The  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>←</kbd>  is an unpublished alternative.

If you do want to change it, then select App Shortcuts. If there's no entry there for Chrome already, press the  <kbd>+</kbd>   at the bottom, select chrome in the list, type the *exact* name of the command you wish to change, then add the command. [If it exists in the list, then just select it before pressing  <kbd>+</kbd> 
It will immediately reflect your changes. Revert to defaults by deleting the entry.

Comment: What do you mean  by "checking the appropriate menu item for next/prev tab?" Is there a box I have to check off, or are you just informing me of the actual default? Also, the exact name of the command is as shown in the answer: "Select previous tab" and "Select next tab?"

Comment: Check as in "look at". Sorry, i'm UK, we don't use the word 'check' to mean "add a tick mark  ✔︎" like the US does … because it's confusing ;) I'm emphasising that the exact text is required because it **is** required. You can do this with any menu, but it you change capitalisation, or you see one with an ellipsis… then using three full-stops ... is not the same thing.Equally if you find one that is contextual you cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

To find the exact spelling, just got to you Chrome menu bar (with Chrome in focus, your system menu bar should have the Chrome menu), and choose the "Tab" menu. There you find "Select next tab" and "Select previous tab".
This is what you need to fill in the App shortcuts mentioned above.

With my latest Chrome update, they changed the capitalisation of the menu items from "Select Next Tab" to "Select next tab" which broke my shortcuts. So I had to redo them. So yes, exact spelling means exact spelling.